# Update query in mysql for new column

Tags: mysql, sql-update

Folks

I have a table as below

[image]

We are suppose to add a new column i.e parent_country after countryname column and result should be as below

```
id parentid  countryname                Parent_country

39  0        Barbados                     Barbados
40  39       Barbados mobile              Barbados
41  39       Mobile Digicel               Barbados
42  0        Anguilla                     Anguilla 
43  42       Anguilla Mobile              Anguilla 
44  42       hello Mobile Digicel         Anguilla
```

Thanks

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: we are able to update for the parentid= 0 only

Comment: Include your query in the question

Comment: but not for parentid<>0

Comment: UPDATE margin1 AS m,
countrycodes AS c SET m.countryname = c.countryname WHERE c.parentid =0 AND m.destination = c.countryname i was using 2 tables but if possible can it be done in 1 table itself

Comment: I don't know if it can be done in one query, could you use an script?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think you should add a column.  You are breaking one of the basic rules of normalization.  Here is a query to give you the results you need.

```
SELECT tbl.id as id
  , tbl.parentid as parentid
  , tbl.countryname as countryname
  , COALESCE(parent.countryname, tbl.countryname) as Parent_country
FROM tbl
LEFT JOIN tbl AS parent
ON tbl.parentid = parent.id
```

And it is easier enough to turn into a view which (while not updateable) can mimic a table for read purposes

```
CREATE VIEW tbl_trick_business_team AS
SELECT tbl.id as id
  , tbl.parentid as parentid
  , tbl.countryname as countryname
  , COALESCE(parent.countryname, tbl.countryname) as Parent_country
FROM tbl
LEFT JOIN tbl AS parent
ON tbl.parentid = parent.id
```

Comment: thanks agRizzo, but i need a new column (parent_country) to use in another table.

Comment: @user1927716 - I can't argue with your business requirements, it is just not a good technological practice.  Could you use a view instead?

Comment: your query is perfectly fine but we needed to update the base table based on this result.

Answer (score 1):

Would not add a column, as the data is obtainable with a selfie join, and breaks normalization - you will use more space in DB. However in some cases it may be beneficial to speed.

but if you have to, here we go

```
ALTER TABLE tablename ADD COLUMN p_name(text);


UPDATE tablename
INNER JOIN
  (SELECT id,
          parentid,
          country_name
   FROM tablename)a ON tablename.parent_id=a.id
SET tablename.p_name=a.country_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the id to `$id` variable and then write the query

```
UPDATE tablename SET Parent_country='Barbados' WHERE id='".$id."' LIMIT 1"
```

Comment: where id='".$id."' SET limit 500